# Button with Handlebar Design Pure CSS No Images

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to design a button that looks like the one below:

[image]

I know it is a localized issue, but I can't seem to make it look like that **without images**

Comment: What do you mean "without images"? Do you have an example JSFiddle or something similar to show what you have tried and which part it is that's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used both a `:before` and `:after` pseudo element in order to achieve and effect like this.

You could then use a combination of CSS transform properties. Something like a rotation with perspective should create the trapezium, and then use borders on another pseudo element to generate the lines.

A quick mockup demo would be:

```css
.demowrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 500px;
  background: lightgray;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px dimgray;
  position: relative;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background: tomato;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  background: inherit;
  top: -18px;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%) perspective(50px) rotateX(45deg);
}
button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 40px;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  top: -8px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
button:hover{
  background:yellow;
```

```html
<div class="demowrapper">
  <button>SELECT your Button</button>
</div>
```